# How to extract url out of the <img> element by js?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I need to extract data (src) from an img element. I tried writing the URL data to the  element and writing to the input.image in the OnClick() function, but it doesn't return anything. If anyone knows how to solve this problem I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance

```
$('#btn').click(function ()
{
    var input = {};
    input.n = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
    input.prompt = $('#txt').val();
    input.size = $('#sel').find(":selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GenerateImage',
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(input)            

    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data.data, function () {

            var btnID = 'VarBtn_' + i;
            $('#display').append(                    
                '<div class="col-md-3 p-10" style="padding-top:10px">' +
                '<div class="dropdown">' +
                '<button class="btnV" id="idOne">Dropdown</button>' +
                '<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">' +                    
                '<br>Select size' +
                '<select id="Vsel">' +
                '<option selected>256x256</option>' +
                '<option>512x512</option>' +
                '<option>1024x1024</option>' +
                '</select>' +
                '<br>Enter quantity' +
                '<input type="number" id="Vquantity" value="1" min="1" max="10" />' +
                '<br>' +
                '<button id="' + btnID + '" >Generate</button>' + 
                '<div hidden id="ImgUrl">"' + this.url + '"</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<img class="p-10" id="GenImg" src = "' + this.url + '">' +
                '</div>');
        });
    });
});

$(document.body).on('click', '[id^=VarBtn]', function () {

var dropdown = $(this).closest('.dropdown-content');
var input = {};
input.size = dropdown.find('#Vsel').val();
input.n = parseInt(dropdown.find('#Vquantity').val()); 

input.image = dropdown.find('#ImgUrl').val(); //return nothing

//code
});
```

Comment: Just get the `src` attribute of the image. `dropdown.find('#ImgUrl').attr("src");`

Comment: I tried. Returns "undefined" instead of a url

Comment: That simply means that the element doesn't exist. You are probably not referencing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataset.

Example:

```
$('#btn').click(function ()
{
    var input = {};
    input.n = parseInt($('#quantity').val());
    input.prompt = $('#txt').val();
    input.size = $('#sel').find(":selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GenerateImage',
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(input)            

    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data.data, function () {

            var btnID = 'VarBtn_' + i;
            $('#display').append(                    
                '<div class="col-md-3 p-10" style="padding-top:10px">' +
                '<div class="dropdown">' +
                '<button class="btnV" data-imgUrl=' + this.url + '" id="idOne">Dropdown</button>' +
                '<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">' +                    
                '<br>Select size' +
                '<select id="Vsel">' +
                '<option selected>256x256</option>' +
                '<option>512x512</option>' +
                '<option>1024x1024</option>' +
                '</select>' +
                '<br>Enter quantity' +
                '<input type="number" id="Vquantity" value="1" min="1" max="10" />' +
                '<br>' +
                '<button id="' + btnID + '" >Generate</button>' + 
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>');
        });
    });
});

$(document.body).on('click', '[id^=VarBtn]', function () {

var dropdown = $(this).closest('.dropdown-content');
var input = {};
input.size = dropdown.find('#Vsel').val();
input.n = parseInt(dropdown.find('#Vquantity').val()); 

input.image = $(this).data("imgUrl");

//code
```

So i recommend use document.createElemet() and parent.appendChild instead of string appending.

Its easy for reading and understandable.

Comment: Why is dataset needed when all the OP wants is the value of the `src` attribute?

Comment: I think **image** element needed only for saving url.
So url can save to dataset.


**Sorry if I'm wrong. I am new contributor in stackoverflow.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).